# Trying to create a maze in C# using a linked list. Can't figure out how to start the game

Tags: c#, maze

I have created the list and the class 'Rooms'. I have added the rooms to the list. Now i am stuck with coding the game play itself. Basically i want to start at room A and can only iterate from Room A to Room E and Room B by pressing the (S)outh button to get to Room E and (W)est button to get to Room B and so on. 
Also i am thinking of calling a different class for game play so the code can be readable. Thus, the main will have just a few lines of code. 
Here is my code. Feel free to point out how to optimise it anyway you can.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication2
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        roomsList theRooms = new roomsList();
        theRooms.allRoomsList();
        theRooms.addRoomToEnd("A");
        theRooms.addRoomToEnd("B");
        theRooms.addRoomToEnd("C");
        theRooms.addRoomToEnd("D");
        theRooms.addRoomToEnd("E");
        theRooms.addRoomToEnd("F");
        theRooms.addRoomToEnd("G");
        theRooms.addRoomToEnd("H");
        theRooms.addRoomToEnd("I");
        theRooms.addRoomToEnd("J");
        theRooms.addRoomToEnd("K");
        theRooms.addRoomToEnd("L");
        Console.WriteLine("What is your name?");
        string playerName = Console.ReadLine();
               Console.WriteLine("================================================================");
        Console.WriteLine(playerName + " You have been Chosen, Enter if you dare!!");
          Console.WriteLine("================================================================");
        Console.WriteLine("(Y)es/(N)o");
        string decision = Console.ReadLine();

        if (decision == "y")
        {
            Console.WriteLine("You need to make you way to Room L, so you may live!!");

        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Goodbye");
        }

    }
}
class rooms //create class rooms
{
    private string roomname;
    private rooms next;

    public rooms(string rname) //constructor
    {
        roomname = rname;
        next = null;
    }
    public void setRoom (rooms nxtRoom)
    {
        next = nxtRoom;
    }
    public rooms ftchNext()
    {
        return next;
    }
    public string ftchName()
    { 
        return roomname;
    }
}//done creating class rooms
class roomsList //create linked list
{
    public rooms start, end;
    public roomsList()
    {
        start = null;
        end = null;
    }
    public void addRoomToEnd(string rname)
    {
        rooms current = new rooms(rname);
        if (end == null)
        {
            start = current;
            end = current;
        }
        else
        {
            end.setRoom(current);
            end = current;
        }
    }
    public void allRoomsList()
    {
        rooms current;
        if (start != null)
        {
            current = start;
            while (current != null)
            {
                current = current.ftchNext();
            }
        }
        else { }
    }
}//class list ends
```

}

Comment: You only keep the next room in the list. This is not enough to make a decision when entering 'w,a,s,d' buttons, since there is four way to go. You need to keep 'forward,left,back,right' rooms as linked to each other instead of just next.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean? Could you please explain further?

Comment: Eran Gat's answer is actually what I am trying to say :) @GidiBloke

Comment: Yea, It helped alot but i don't understand some parts of it. Can you please take a crack at it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Overall, it looks like you are in the right track, but there is some key functionality missing. Here are a few points that you can use to finish your implementation

First, the problem statement, as I understand it from your question: Your maze is a collection of rooms. You can move between rooms by going north, south, east or west. You finish the maze when you get to some room which is defined as the exit.

**Room Class:** Your room should keep this notion that it can be connected to different rooms. I would suggest the following:

```
class Room 
{
   public string Name;
   public Room NorthRoom;
   public Room SouthRoom;
   public Room EastRoom;
   public Room WestRoom;
   pulic bool isExit;

   public ConnectTo(Room room, Direction direction)
   {
       // Add room connection logic here...
   }
}
```

**Maze Class:** The maze class has a starting room, and that's it. To create the maze, you will create rooms and connect between them as appropriate.

```
class Maze
{
   public Room StartingRoom;
}
```

So how can we create a Maze? I will show a naive way, but here is where you can code some helper functions to make it easier for you.

```
//Lets say we want to have the following maze:
//
// start - room 1 - room 2
//           |        |
//         room 3   room 4 (exit) 

var maze = new Maze();
var startingRoom = new Room();
maze.StartingRoom = startingRoom;
var room1 = new Room();
var room2 = new Room();
var room3 = new Room();
var room4 = new Room();
room4.IsExit = true;
startingRoom.ConnectTo(room1, "East");
room1.ConnectTo(room2, "East");
room1.ConnectTo(room3, "South");
room2.ConnectTo(room4, "South");
```

To implement connect to, check the direction you get as input and set the appropriate room (north, south, etc.).

**Playing the Game** : In your main class, after the user agrees to start, have a while loop that will stop when a user enters a room which has IsExit = true. You keep track of the current room in which the user is. They start out in the start of the maze. The user selects if they want to go N,S,E,W. Depending on  their choice, you will move the current room to the North, South, East, West rooms respectivly. You need to deal with the case where some of the rooms may be null.

Hope that this gives you enough thinking points to complete your game!

Comment: Does this mean i will need to create another class 'Direction'. Also how does the connection logic work? I am guessing that is how to set the routes of the maze, how 1 particular room can only lead to another set of rooms and nowhere else. Forgive my naivety, i an very new to the language.

Comment: Direction is not necessary class, you can pass a string value such as "w" for "north side room" of the current room to connect. One object of a class is okay to lead to other rooms. Think you have a "Room" object and it has 4 other room objects which are "west, east north, south" and each direction room has its own rooms and it goes like that. You have one starting room and you have to connect others to it. So, after completion of connection operation you have a maze with starting room. Is it clear or another question? @GidiBloke

Comment: @GidiBloke - Added some more details.

Comment: Thanks for your help so far. I have managed to get it to work but there is still some functionality i want to add to the game so please help if you can. 1. I want the user to be able to type 'Quit' and 'Start Again' to quit the console application or start again at any point in the game.

Comment: Sounds like a nice functionality! At this point, you should have some point in your program that handles the user's input, like N,S,E,W. If you are getting this input as a char, first change it to a string so you could handle strings like quit or start over. To handle quit, just close your console application (you just return). For start again, you need to keep a variable of the current position in the maze. If the users chooses to start over, just set the current position to be maze.StartingRoom. Good luck!

Comment: This might be a little too late but thanks for your help @PartlyCloudy.